# Cannot add EntityFrameworkCore Tools to class library in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2017

I created a new Class Library (.Net Core) and wanted to add the package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet 1.0.0`. However I refuses and I get the following error

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       Package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet 1.0.0' has a package type 'DotnetCliTool' that is not supported by project 'MyVS2017Project'.           0

I also tried it in a Class Library (.Net Framework)

Same error message when using the Package Manager Console command

> Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet

Answer (score 7):

CLI tool packages cannot be added as standard package references. You need something like this in your csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
<DotNetCliToolReference 
    Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" 
    Version="1.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

This is a bug/limitation in NuGet. See https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4190 for more details.